# KM Player latest version issue. How to solve the issue?

Tags: windows, video, video-playback, kmplayer

I am using KM player for the past few years. Recently I have updated to latest version (2020.3.24.15) before that the old version which I was using had the option to "start playback in half size etc." This is unavailable in the new version. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Try <alt><1> ...

Comment: I just want to come by default by clicking on the video automatically.